# Get last time within each member of a dimension has data

Tags: ssas, mdx

In a cube, There is a time [DimDate].[Date] and location [DimLocation].[State] dimension. I want to find out what is the last date for each state in which that state has data (is not empty).

Comment: These are two dimensions.  I'm guessing you need a fact table that is related to both of these.  For example, if you had sales data, you would want the last date for which each state had a sale.  If this isn't the case, please post more info about your schema and how these two dimensions are related.

Comment: Exactly, it's what I'm looking for. The real case is the last date for which each state had at least one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
With Member [Measures].[LastTransDate] as
TAIL(
        NONEMPTY(
            [Date].[Date].[Date]
            ,[Measures].[Transaction]
        )
        ,1
    ).Item(0).MemberValue

Select {[Measures].[LastTransDate]} on 0, 
NON EMPTY { [DimLocation].[State].children} on 1
from [Cube]
```

This creates a calculated member based upon your date dimension member, looking for the last date that is not empty for the transaction measure.  You didn't provide a measure name, so you will have to replace [Measures].[Transaction] with whatever your measure is. The NON EMPTY on 1 will remove any states that don't have transactions.